# Postgres requires providing Primary key explicitly though the type is serial

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t_sample (
    sample_pk SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    lis_pkref bigint NOT NULL,
    patient_pkref bigint NOT NULL,  
    sample_lis_id  varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

If I try to execute an insert query:

```
INSERT INTO t_sample VALUES(0, 0, 'S123' )
```

it fails with error:

```
LINE 5: INSERT INTO t_sample VALUES(0, 0, 'S123' )
                                          ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: not valid syntax for integer: „S123“ (I've translated it)
SQL Status:22P02
```

This query works:

```
INSERT INTO t_sample VALUES(0, 0, 0, 'S123' )
```

Doesn't `serial` create the value for the column automatically like auto_increment in MySQL? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `INSERT INTO t_sample VALUES(0, 0, 'S123' )` would not work in MySQL either - it would result in an error "*Column count doesn't match value count*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify the columns that you want to provide a value for in your `INSERT` statement which is bad coding style to begin with.

Only list the columns you need and the serial will work just fine:

```
insert into t_sample (lis_pkref, patient_pkref, sample_lis_id)
values (0, 0, 'S123' );
```

Another alternative is to supply the `default` clause:

```
insert into t_sample (sample_pk, lis_pkref, patient_pkref, sample_lis_id)
values (default, 0, 0, 'S123' );
```

or - without mentioning the columns

```
insert into t_sample
values (default, 0, 0, 'S123' );
```

But: not specifying the columns in the `INSERT` statement is going to get you in trouble in the long run. You should always explicitly list them!

Do **not** specify the value `0` for the serial column. Unlike MySQL, Postgres tries to store the value exactly as you supply it - MySQL silently converts e.g. a value of `0` to an auto-increment value.

---

The reason for the error message is that with the statement `INSERT INTO t_sample VALUES(0, 0, 'S123' )` Postgres (or actually *any* DBMS) expects values for the first three columns of the table. In the sample table the first three columns are integers and thus `'S123'` can't be inserted as it is not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

It does, but you have to tell PostgreSQL which values you are providing.

```
INSERT INTO t_sample (lis_pkref, patient_pkref, sample_lis_id) VALUES (0, 0, 'S123' )
```

If you don't, it naturally starts from the first one. It doesn't skip any columns in any case.